# data.table adding column to several data tables in loop

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having a very simple problem, but have not found a way out of it. I was given about 200 tables from different stores, and have to analyze the whole body of data *as a unit*. As the tables are fairly big, I'm working with `data.table::fread`. My plan is loading each table, `rbind`ing them together and proceed with the analysis. In order to retain which store is which, I'd like to add a variable store to each table, with the name of the store(same as the table). For that I planned to run a for loop with the names of the tables and create the new variable.

```
# I'll create some dummy data tables here. In reality they're loaded with fread
library(data.table)
centro <- data.table(x=letters[1:5], y = 1:5)
sur <- data.table(x=letters[2:7], y = 3:8)
...
norte <- data.table(x=letters[2:10], y = 3:11)
```

I need each table to have a variable "store" whose value is "centro", "sur" or "norte", depending on the store it belongs to. So I tried:

```
st <- c("centro", "sur", "norte")
for (i in st){
   i[, store := i]
}
```

Which, of course, didn't work (it complains that "i is not a data.table"). I then tried to create a list and try it via `lapply`:

```
sts <- list(centro, sur, norte)
sts <- lapply(sts, function(z) z[, store := names(z)])
```

Which doesn't work because `names(z)` are "x", "y" and "store".

How can I do this with a loop (or a *pply function), instead of manually doing `xyz[, store := "xyz"]` ?

**side notes**

- the naming of the variables is almost impossible to adjust, and doesn't follow any pattern (nothing like store_1, store_2, etc)
- I may be very biased with the alternative I described. Any other thing that works will be ok.

Comment: Your chunk of code with `i[, store := i]` is not reproducible, `i` is a character scalar, and you are subsetting it with `[` and trying to use `:=` inside. Start from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to store your objects in a list and then access them by indexing the list.

```
library(data.table)

my_dts <- list (
  centro = data.table(x=letters[1:5], y = 1:5),
  sur = data.table(x=letters[2:7], y = 3:8),
  norte = data.table(x=letters[2:10], y = 3:11)
)

st <- c("centro", "sur", "norte")
for (i in st) my_dts[[i]][, store := i]
```

Comment: This one was very obvious, thanks. Those are the kind of solutions that DOESN'T come to mind after too many hours / too few coffee.

Comment: `my_dts[[i]][, store := i]` doesn't actually work. `for (i in 1:length(my_dts)) my_dts[[i]][, store := st[i]]` does.

Comment: works for me. you can index a list by name, if the list has names, which it does in the example above. you can also index by number though, so your comment works too

Comment: Sure, I just listed the variables I had in workspace, so that's why it didn't work. It does, as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

### Direct answer, very little change

Wrap `get` around `i`, and assign the value back to the name contained in `i`.

```
for (i in st){
  assign(i, get(i)[, store := i])
}
```

### Better system, some manipulation

Store the tables in a list and use the method proposed @arvi1000.
A couple very obvious advantages

1. Since your individual stores are all items under a list, your workspace has about 200 fewer objects in it, which is nice when you `ls()`.
2. You can use `lapply` instead of a for loop, which usually means cleaner code
3. You can use `AllStore <- do.call(what = rbind, args = my_dts)`.

### 'More Better', back to the beginning

- When you read in the data from different stores, set the value of the
  `store` variable then. Use `lapply` and an anonymous function to do this.
- Don't bother saving the `my_dts` list, because
  it's just duplication of data that will be saved in `all_stores`
  anyway.

Coincidentally, I had a similar business problem last week, and this is the method I used, working with about 250 csvs. Here's how I think your code would look.

```
st <- c("centro", "sur", "norte")

all_stores <- do.call(
  what = rbind,
  args = lapply(
    X = st,
    FUN = function(storeNM){
      temp <- fread(input = paste0(storeNM, '.csv'))
      temp[, store := storeNM]
      return(temp)
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing `get`, That was the function I was looking for. However, it doesn't work as you proposed (`get(i)[, store := i]`), as it doesn't actually modify the object. An assignment will be required: `i <- get(i)[, store := i]`

Comment: In my previous comment, should be `assign(i, get(i)[, store := i])`

Comment: True statement. I didn't think about (but I should have); `get` returns by value, which means that the by reference qualities of `[.data.table` all go out the window. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i in st)
{
eval(parse(text=i))[, ':='(store = i)]
}
```

On second thoughts , probably this is better. Assuming you have all your datasets read in using `s<-lapply(filepathlist,fread)` then use:

```
st <- c("centro", "sur", "norte") # need to change this to a list of datasets you read in    
st2<-lapply(st,function(i){eval(parse(text=i))[, ':='(store = i)]})
st3<-rbindlist(st2)
```

Output:

```
    > st3
        x  y  store
     1: a  1 centro
     2: b  2 centro
     3: c  3 centro
     4: d  4 centro
     5: e  5 centro
     6: b  3    sur
     7: c  4    sur
     8: d  5    sur
     9: e  6    sur
    10: f  7    sur
    11: g  8    sur
    12: b  3  norte
    13: c  4  norte
    14: d  5  norte
    15: e  6  norte
    16: f  7  norte
    17: g  8  norte
    18: h  9  norte
    19: i 10  norte
    20: j 11  norte
```

Comment: as with `get` in @Adam's answer, the `eval(parse(text = i))[, store := i]` piece doesn't actually change the variable, it does require the assignment: `assign(i, eval(parse(text = i))[, store := i])`

Comment: Agreed, assignment is required, `eval(parse(...))` will just evaluate references to variable. I find @arvi1000 answer better with list of datasets.